# How to determine if printer is xps ? c#

Tags: c#, xps, printers

How to determine if printer is xps?
I found way to get property "Published" from wmi (it set to false if device is not physical), but i want to determine if printer is xps writer.
Thanks

Comment: Unless the user changes the name of the printer (unlikely), could you not just go on the name? It is called "XPS Writer", after all.

Comment: I can use any printer identifiers or info that can be retrived from wmi or registry etc.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the printer is the "Xps Document Writer", or just any XPS print driver? Why do you need this information? There may be a simpler way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printers are defined by the driver they use, not their name, so an XPS printer will use the driver  `Microsoft XPS Document Writer`.  This will be a reliable test until a third party creates another XPS print driver with a different name, which I don't expect to happen anytime soon, if ever.

Comment: I created an XPS print driver with a different name. Also the Microsoft Enhanced Point and Print driver is an XPS driver. Finally Windows 8 comes with XPS Mono and XPS Color generic drivers.

Comment: I stand corrected, but it's still the only reliable way to determine if a printer is XPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you detect from CPrintInfo class, printing to XPS file returns following values -

```html
CPrintInfo::m_pPD->GetDriverName() returns "winspool"
CPrintInfo::m_pPD->GetDeviceName() returns "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
CPrintInfo::m_pPD->GetPortName() returns "XPSPort:"
```

So, it might be safe enough to assume if it is XPS or not by checking device name and port name.

Comment: I answered in C++ by mistake. :)